# MySQL. Нахождение значения у максимального и минимального времени группы

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица (Время, Цена, Объем)

Необходимо найти в заданном промежутке времени по определенному интервалу значения:

- **цена у минимального времени интервала, (не сделано)**
- **цена у максимального времени    интервала, (не сделано)**
- максимальная цена,
- минимальная цена,
- объем.

Что сделал: интервал в примере 3 дня, может быть хоть год или пару секунд и т.д.

```
SELECT 
    FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.TimeAdded)/(60 * 60 * 24 * 3)) AS timekey, 
    min(t1.TimeAdded), max(t1.TimeAdded),   
    min(t1.Price) as min_price, max(t1.Price) as max_price,
    SUM(t1.Quantity) as volume
FROM TradeFill as t1
WHERE t1.TimeAdded >= "2018-01-01 00:00:00" AND t1.TimeAdded <= "2018-08-10 23:59:59"
GROUP BY timekey;


SELECT VERSION()
5.5.56-MariaDB

CREATE TABLE `TradeFill` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Price` decimal(32,20) NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` decimal(32,20) NOT NULL,
  `TimeAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10370 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Таблица

```
ID-----Price-----Quantity-----TimeAdded
1------2000------10-----------2018-08-09 00:01:00
2------5000------10-----------2018-08-09 00:02:00
3------1000------10-----------2018-08-09 00:03:00
4------7000------10-----------2018-08-09 00:05:00
5------3000------10-----------2018-08-09 00:04:00
6------2500------15-----------2018-08-10 00:00:00
```

Хочу видеть

```
min(t1.TimeAdded)-------max(t1.TimeAdded)-----PriceStart-----PriceFinish-----min_price-----max_price-----volume
2018-08-09 00:01:00-----2018-08-09 00:05:00---2000-----------3000------------1000----------7000----------50----
2018-08-10 00:00:00-----2018-08-10 00:00:00---2500-----------2500------------2500----------2500----------15----
```

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE TradeFill и SELECT VERSION() в студию.

Comment: @Akina Добавил.

Comment: Отлично. Осталось понять, чем не устраивает написанный запрос.

Comment: @Akina нету цены у максимального и минимального времени данного интервала

Comment: Жаль, твоя версия не поддерживает оконные функции, придётся использовать подзапросы. Проще всего получить требуемые значения по отдельности. Типа 'SELECT price AS price_for_min_time FROM  TradeFill WHERE TimeAdded >= @periodStart ORDER BY TimeAdded ASC LIMIT 1', аналогично для максимального времени. Чтобы не морочиться (итогом всего запроса всё равно будет одна запись), подзапросы можно встроить непосредственно в секцию вывода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как думаете так сойдет?

```
SELECT tr1.Price as PriceStart, 
       tr2.Price as PriceFinish, 
       tr3.* 
FROM TradeFill as tr1, 
     TradeFill as tr2, 
     (SELECT 
        FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.TimeAdded)/(1 * 1 * 1 * 1)) AS timekey, 
        min(t1.Id) as min_id,
        max(t1.Id) as max_id,
        min(t1.TimeAdded) as t_min, 
        max(t1.TimeAdded) as t_max,
        min(t1.Price) as min_price, 
        max(t1.Price) as max_price,
        SUM(t1.Quantity) as volume
    FROM 
        TradeFill as t1
    WHERE t1.TimeAdded BETWEEN "2018-01-01 00:00:00" AND "2018-08-10 23:59:59"
    GROUP BY timekey
    ) as tr3
WHERE tr1.Id = tr3.min_id 
  AND tr2.Id = tr3.max_id
```

Comment: Eсли тебя устраивает - о чём речь?

Comment: @Akina запрос вроде рабочий и вроде не медленный, но правильно ли я так делаю

Comment: Я форматнул код, чтобы было видно, что происходит... Ну так вроде нормально, логика соблюдается. Хотя мне не нравится, что вместо минимального/максимального времени (как по заданию) берётся минимальный/максимальный ID. Тут бы я поправил для строгости (и соответственно условия отбора из tr1/tr2 изменить с ID на время).

Comment: @Akina я сделал так первое значение и последнее значение у данного интервала и вывел их цену. Типа на старте была такая цена, на выходе такая. Если таким образом поменять задачу, то пойдет?

Comment: Это всё понятно. Вот только начало/конец периода определяется временем, а не уникальным идентификатором записи. Т.е. в подзапросе получать `min_id` и `max_id` вообще не нужно, а `tr1` и `tr2` связывать по `tr1.TimeAdded = t3.t_min AND tr2.TimeAdded = t3.t_max`. Иначе можешь налететь на неприятность, если по какой-то причине блок данных был пропущен, и добавлен впоследствии, получив ID с нарушенным порядком.

Comment: @Akina а если у меня одинаковое время до секунды в интервале, тогда у нас количество записей на выходе увеличится же

Comment: A у Вас реально так бывает, что на одну и ту же точку времени есть две различные записи? Потому как по физике процесса этого быть не должно... и соответственно в структуре время должно быть уникальным. Нет, я понимаю, что автозаполнение поля штампа времени и не такого может накосорезить - но я не могу понять смысла наличия двух разных цен в один и тот же момент.

Comment: Да, к сожаления у нас такое бывает, цена варьируется от курса, таблица на самом деле гораздо сложнее. Но смысл от этого не меняется. Я учел твои замечания, сейчас подумаю как можно это решить.

Comment: Тогда надо ориентироваться на другое поле - не на время ДОБАВЛЕНИЯ записи, а на время АКТУАЛЬНОСТИ записи. Сто пудов у тебя такое поле имеется, просто в вопросе не показано.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @periodStart := "2018-01-01 00:00:00";
SET @periodEnd := "2018-08-10 23:59:59";    

SELECT 
    FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.TimeAdded)/(60 * 60 * 24 * 3)) AS timekey, 
    min(t1.TimeAdded) AS min_time, 
    ( SELECT price
      FROM TradeFill 
      WHERE TimeAdded >= @periodStart 
      ORDER BY TimeAdded ASC 
      LIMIT 1 )  AS price_for_min_time,
    max(t1.TimeAdded) AS max_time,   
    ( SELECT price
      FROM TradeFill 
      WHERE TimeAdded <= @periodEnd
      ORDER BY TimeAdded DESC
      LIMIT 1 )  AS price_for_max_time,
    min(t1.Price) as min_price, 
    max(t1.Price) as max_price,
    SUM(t1.Quantity) as volume
FROM TradeFill as t1
WHERE t1.TimeAdded >= @periodStart 
  AND t1.TimeAdded <= @periodEnd
GROUP BY timekey;
```

Comment: price_for_min_time - минимальное время у данного интервала, посмотри мой вариант кода, я его в ответах записал. А у тебя получается что для всей таблицы

Comment: @Barlukov *у тебя получается что для всей таблицы* Нет. `WHERE TimeAdded >= @periodStart` видишь? фиг он дал выгрести из ВСЕЙ таблицы. PS. Замени таблицу с образцом данных на вменяемый INSERT INTO с данными (в т.ч. и за пределами заданного интервала выборки) или создай fiddle.

Comment: есть период 10 дней с интервалом 1 день, итого записей будет 10. У каждой записи свой price_for_min_time и price_for_max_time. Ты получается находишь только с данного периода, а надо интервала

Comment: То есть, говоря "по определенному интервалу", ты имел в виду "для каждого интервала отдельно в пределах заданного периода"?

Comment: Да, все верно))