# Составить запрос с интервалом без пропусков

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть таблица:

```
TimeAdded                 Price 
2018-08-15 00:01:00       200
2018-08-15 00:02:00       300
2018-08-15 00:07:00       150
2018-08-15 00:07:59       100
2018-08-15 00:11:00       200

2018-08-15 10:00:00       50
```

Нужно найти в диапазоне  `2018-08-15 00:01:00 - 2018-08-15 01:00:00` с интервалом 2 минуты найти сумму цены

Должный результат:

```
TimeStart              TimeFinish            sum(Price)
2018-08-15 00:00:00    2018-08-15 00:01:59   200
2018-08-15 00:02:00    2018-08-15 00:03:59   300
2018-08-15 00:04:00    2018-08-15 00:05:59   0
2018-08-15 00:06:00    2018-08-15 00:07:59   250
2018-08-15 00:08:00    2018-08-15 00:09:59   0
2018-08-15 00:10:00    2018-08-15 00:11:59   200
...
...
...
2018-08-15 00:58:00    2018-08-15 00:59:59   -
```

Т.е. основной смысл в том чтобы даже если в таблице нет данных данного интервала, то выводить интервал только с нулевыми значениями

**UPD:** 
Запрос который я составил можно ознакомиться тут: 
[MySQL. Нахождение значения у максимального и минимального времени группы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866715/mysql-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B/866809)

Вопрос в том, что у меня в запросе составляется интервал из данных в таблице, а как сделать интервал как я предоставил

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81733/discussion-on-question-by-barlukov------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Для **MySql 8**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iMTe65UDpYpHypsTTdDj1f/1)

```
create table `TableSource`(
  `TimeAdded` datetime,
  `Price`  int);
  insert into `TableSource` ( `TimeAdded`,`Price`) values 
('2018-08-15 00:01:00',       200),
('2018-08-15 00:02:00',       300),
('2018-08-15 00:07:00',       150),
('2018-08-15 00:07:59',       100),
('2018-08-15 00:11:00',       200),
('2018-08-15 10:00:00',        50);
```

Ограничение: Создание последовательности на 3 дня от начала интервала.

Был бы сервер MS SQL Server или Postgresql можно было бы использовать [подобное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/859913/299964) и тогда ограничения снялись.

```
WITH 
`maxmin` (`vmin`, `vmax`) AS 
  (SELECT MIN( `TimeAdded`), MAX( `TimeAdded`) FROM `TableSource`),
`maxmincorrect` (`vmin`, `vmax`) AS
  (select 
    DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE(`vmin`),
     INTERVAL HOUR(`vmin`) HOUR),
     INTERVAL FLOOR((MINUTE(`vmin`))/2)*2 MINUTE) as `vmin`,
    DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE(`vmax`),
     INTERVAL HOUR(`vmax`) HOUR),
     INTERVAL FLOOR((MINUTE(`vmax`))/2)*2 MINUTE) as `vmax`
   from `maxmin`),
`seq` (`TimeStart`,`TimeFinish`) AS
  (
  select 
    DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(t3.`d`,INTERVAL t2.`h` HOUR),INTERVAL 10*t1.m1 + t0.m0 MINUTE) `TimeStart`,
    DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(t3.`d`,INTERVAL t2.`h` HOUR),INTERVAL 10*t1.m1 + t0.m0 + 119 SECOND) `TimeFinish`
  from 
  (
    (select DATE(`vmin`) `d` from `maxmincorrect`
    union select DATE_ADD(DATE(`vmin`),INTERVAL 1 DAY) from `maxmincorrect`
    union select DATE_ADD(DATE(`vmin`),INTERVAL 2 DAY) from `maxmincorrect`
    ) t3
    cross join
    (select 0 `h`
    union select 1 
    union select 2 
    union select 3 
    union select 4
    union select 5
    union select 6
    union select 7
    union select 8
    union select 9
    union select 10
    union select 11
    union select 12
    union select 13
    union select 14
    union select 15
    union select 16
    union select 17
    union select 18
    union select 19
    union select 20
    union select 21
    union select 22
    union select 23
    ) t2
    cross join
    (select 0 m1 
    union select 1 
    union select 2 
    union select 3 
    union select 4
    union select 5
    ) t1
    cross join
    (select 0 m0 
    union select 2 
    union select 4 
    union select 6 
    union select 8
    ) t0
    ) 
  where 
    DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(t3.`d`,INTERVAL t2.`h` HOUR),INTERVAL 10*t1.m1 + t0.m0 MINUTE)  between 
    (select `vmin` from `maxmincorrect`) and 
    (select DATE_ADD(`vmax`, INTERVAL 119 SECOND) from `maxmincorrect`)
  )   

select 
  `seq`.`TimeStart`,
  `seq`.`TimeFinish`,
  COALESCE(sum(`TableSource`.`Price`),0)
from `seq` 
  left outer join `TableSource` 
  on `TableSource`.`TimeAdded` between `seq`.`TimeStart` and `seq`.`TimeFinish`
group by 
  `seq`.`TimeStart`,
  `seq`.`TimeFinish`
ORDER BY 
  `seq`.`TimeStart`,
  `seq`.`TimeFinish`
```

А для **MySql 5.6** проще одним запросом получить граничные значения далее их использовать. Можно граничные значение клиентов и дальше из включить в основной запрос или можно создать хранимую процедуру.

```
-- Получили граничные значение
select 
 convert(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE(`vmin`),
   INTERVAL HOUR(`vmin`) HOUR),
   INTERVAL FLOOR((MINUTE(`vmin`))/2)*2 MINUTE), datetime) as `vmin`,
 convert(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE(`vmax`),
   INTERVAL HOUR(`vmax`) HOUR),
   INTERVAL FLOOR((MINUTE(`vmax`))/2)*2 MINUTE), datetime) as `vmax`
into 
  @vmin,
  @vmax
from (
  SELECT 
    MIN(`TimeAdded`) `vmin`,
    MAX(`TimeAdded`) `vmax`
  FROM `TableSource`
) `maxmin`
;

-- Основной запрос
select
  `seq`.`TimeStart`,
  `seq`.`TimeFinish`,
  COALESCE(sum(`TableSource`.`Price`),0)
FROM
  (
  select 
    convert(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(t3.`d`,INTERVAL t2.`h` HOUR),INTERVAL 10*t1.m1 + t0.m0 MINUTE), datetime) `TimeStart`,
    convert(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(t3.`d`,INTERVAL t2.`h` HOUR),INTERVAL 10*t1.m1 + t0.m0 + 119 SECOND), datetime) `TimeFinish`
  from 
    (select @vmin `d`
    union select DATE_ADD(DATE(@vmin),INTERVAL 1 DAY) `d`
    union select DATE_ADD(DATE(@vmin),INTERVAL 2 DAY) `d`
    ) t3
    cross join
    (select 0 `h`
    union select 1 
    union select 2 
    union select 3 
    union select 4
    union select 5
    union select 6
    union select 7
    union select 8
    union select 9
    union select 10
    union select 11
    union select 12
    union select 13
    union select 14
    union select 15
    union select 16
    union select 17
    union select 18
    union select 19
    union select 20
    union select 21
    union select 22
    union select 23
    ) t2
    cross join
    (select 0 m1 
    union select 1 
    union select 2 
    union select 3 
    union select 4
    union select 5
    ) t1
    cross join
    (select 0 m0 
    union select 2 
    union select 4 
    union select 6 
    union select 8
    ) t0
  ) `seq`
  left outer join `TableSource` 
  on `TableSource`.`TimeAdded` between `seq`.`TimeStart` and `seq`.`TimeFinish`
where 
    `seq`.`TimeStart` >=  @vmin 
    and `seq`.`TimeFinish` <= DATE_ADD(@vmax, INTERVAL 119 SECOND)
group by 
  `seq`.`TimeStart`,
  `seq`.`TimeFinish`
ORDER BY 
  `seq`.`TimeStart`,
  `seq`.`TimeFinish`  
;
```

Comment: а при чем здесь c#?

Comment: Класс, а вот для MySql 5.6 если интервал будет скажем 10 минут или один день, как стоит поменять код?

Comment: это для 3-х дней:  (select @vmin `d`
    union select DATE_ADD(DATE(@vmin),INTERVAL 1 DAY) `d`
    union select DATE_ADD(DATE(@vmin),INTERVAL 2 DAY) `d`
    ) t3

Comment: для 1-го дня:  (select @vmin `d`
    ) t3

Comment: и лучше оставить на 2 дня
т.е. например интервал попадает на переход с 2018.08.15 23:56  на 2018.08.16 00:03  тогда создаются интервала на два дня , ненужные части обрезаются,
а если запрос настроить на один день, то войдут значения только 2018.08.15 ,  а  2018.08.16 не войдут, и можно на клиенте формировать длительность, т.е. нашли начало и конец интервала отрезали время, нашли разницу в днях, динамически в запросе сформировали нужное количество дней, отправили его на выполнение